# How to extract the date from string formatted date in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to extract the date as the format `2008-07-06` from this date  `Sunday 6th July 2008` format.

I have tried as below by using below two functions

```
select str_to_date('Sunday 6th July 2008','%Y-%m-%d')
select DATE_FORMAT('Sunday 6th July 2008','%Y-%m-%d')
```

but it will returning null value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `STR_TO_DATE`:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Sunday 6th July 2008', '%W %D %M %Y')
FROM dual;
```

The default date format in MySQL already is `2008-07-06`, so you should not have to make a second call to `DATE_FORMAT`.

### SQLFiddle

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution it is working well.